I'm looking for alternative methods to securely pass data without exposing it in the URL parameters in Blazor WebAssembly (.NET 8)
I'm creating a wizard form in a Blazor Server .NET 8 application using @InteractiveServerRenderMode. The purpose of this app is to serve as a database migration tool, and I need to pass the connection string between components. I want to avoid sending this sensitive data in URL parameters. Since a database isn't necessary for this task, is there a recommended way to pass data between components without using URL parameters?
I explored using URL parameters to pass data between components by reading this: Fundamentals of Routing in Blazor - Microsoft Docs. I'm looking for alternative methods to securely pass data without exposing it in the URL or relying on a database, as it's not needed for this task.
In the component FromServer.razor, I have the following setup:
razor

//NavMenu.razor 
<MudNavMenu>
    <MudNavLink Href="/" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Dashboard</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/serverconn" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" >Server</MudNavLink>   
</MudNavMenu>

//FromServer.razor
@page "/serverconn" 
@inject NavigationManager nav; 

//ui
    <MudButton 
        Variant="Variant.Filled" 
        Size="Size.Large" 
        Color="Color.Info"
        OnClick="(()=>GoToTableGrid(DatabaseName, ConnectionString))"
        Disabled="!IsConnected">Continue</MudButton>
</MudItem>
@code{
     protected void Return() 
    { 
    nav.NavigateTo("/tablegrid"); 
    }
}



//DataTableGrid.razor
@page "/tablegrid"
//ui
<MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Medium" Class="mt-10">
    <MudPaper Class="pa-2" Elevation="0">
                <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Align="Align.Center">SELECT TABLES</MudText>
                <MudTable @ref="Table"
                          T="string"
                          FixedHeader="true"
                          Striped="true"
                          Items="@ListOfTables"
             
             MultiSelection="true"
                          SelectionChangeable="_selectionChangeable"
                          Hover="true"
                          @bind-SelectedItems="selectedItems"
                          OnRowClick="@OnRowClick"
                          SelectOnRowClick="@_selectOnRowClick">
                    <HeaderContent>                       
                        <MudTh>Table Name</MudTh>
                    </HeaderContent>
                    <RowTemplate>
                        <MudTd DataLabel="Table Name"><MudIcon Icon="@gc.TableIcon" /> dbo.@context</MudTd>
                    </RowTemplate>
                </MudTable>            
                <MudButton OnClick="Return">Volver</MudButton>              
    </MudPaper>
</MudContainer>

@code{
 
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
     await LoadDBTables();
     StateHasChanged();

 }
//DbName & DbConn are the values I want you to supply.
public async Task LoadDBTables(string DbName, string DbConn)
{
    string Query = "SELECT * FROM sys.tables ORDER BY name;";    
            FirstDBconn = FirstDBconn.Replace("master", SelectedDB);
            try
            {
                using (var dbContext = new SqlServerDBContext(FirstDBconn))
                {
                    var dataServices = new DataServicesTest(dbContext);
                    ListOfTables = await dataServices.QueryDBWithEfCore(Query);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the error for debugging and notify the user appropriately
                Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error fetching data: {ex.Message}");
                // Handle the error, e.g., display an error message to the user
            } 
 }

}


POST instead of GET.  But "I need to pass the connection string between components." seems like a very bad idea.  You should not have to do that.  HTTPS will secure parameters in GETs and POSTs, but GETs are more likely to show up in logs, which are not encrypted.  Your wizard steps can be done completely from the front-end.  (and you can use hashes for back/forward support if desired...)

The whole idea of allowing DB migrations from front-end seems like a recipe for disaster.

I’m not using POST or GET requests; instead, I'm using the routing provided by ASP.NET Core. This is a server-side app, where I’m primarily using MudBlazor for the UI. The processing is handled by the server using EF Core, with multiple databases involved.

you can route it however you like, but to avoid passing those params in URL you need a method other than GET... (you'd bind those values via FromForm, or FromBody).

either way you should not need to pass any connection strings. Those should never leave the server... any actual access to DB should be user-level (the app pool) and restricted to strictly necessary actions.  You should consider the consequences of a malicious client sending a connection string that's actually executed on the server.

what I mean by not a GET is that params in the URL, are usually GETs.  Or at least the controller will bind to the params in the URL.  Non-GET verbs, send params in the body of the request, not the URL.   So you can send and bind to the body of the request instead of the URL params.  The only other option would be using a custom header. (which is sort of nice if it's required as it would help prevent CSRF attacks... in general GETs should never "change state" or make any changes in back end to help mitigate CSRF as well)

I suggest you could consider using the Browser storage's session storage to store it at the client side.
SessionStorage is scoped to the browser tab. If the user reloads the tab, the state persists. If the user closes the tab or the browser, the state is lost. If the user opens multiple browser tabs, each tab has its own independent version of the data.
Generally, sessionStorage is safer to use. sessionStorage avoids the risk that a user opens multiple tabs and encounters the following:
ASP.NET Core Protected Browser Storage uses ASP.NET Core Data Protection to protect the data.
More details you could refer to this article.
Please notice: By using this feature, I suggest you disable the prerender , because the localStorage or sessionStorage aren't available during prerendering.
<Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)" />

Example:
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedSessionStorage ProtectedSessionStore

Store the connection string:
  await ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("connectionstring", "test");

Take it from the other component:
  var connection =  await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<string>("connectionstring" );
  var reuslt = connection.Success ? connection.Value : "not set yet";

Result:


This clarifies a lot. I read the article you mentioned and watched some videos on state management in the Blazor Train series, which helped resolve my question.
